# To prove certain derivative approximations

Tags: calculus

> Please, carefully prove that
>
> $$ f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}{h} + O(h) $$
>
> using taylor series

### Attempt

By definition, we know the taylor series of $f(z)$ at $z=x$ is given by

$$ f(z) = f(x) + f'(x)(z-x) + \frac{f''(x)}{2!}(z-x)^2 + ... + \frac{ f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!} (z-x)^{n+1} $$

where $c \in (x,z)$ and this converges for values $|z-x|<R$. Putting $z=x+h$, we obtain

$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + \frac{f''(x)}{2!}h^2 + ... + \frac{ f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!} h^{n+1} $$

Now, dont we need $f''(x)$ to be bounded?? so that in this case we obtain

$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x) h + O(h^2) $$

Dividing by $h \neq 0$ we obtain

$$ f'(x) = \frac{ f(x+h) - f(x) }{h} + O(h) $$

here is my second question, am I allowed to have $O(h^2)/h = O(h) $?

Comment: Are you trying to prove the formula for a real analytic $f$?

Comment: I guess I can assume that. Analytic means that all derivatives of f exists right?

Comment: Going in the direction of copper.hat, can you precise the hypothesis regarding your map $f$? Domain, codomain, smoothness...

Comment: Without precise hypotheses it is hard to give a precise answer :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need $f''$ to be bounded for the equality to be possible. For instance, take $f(x)=x^3$. Then
\begin{align}
f'(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h&=3x^2-\frac{(x+h)^3-x^3}{h}\\ 
&=3x^2-(3x^2+3xh+h^3)\\
&=3xh+h^3
\end{align}
If you take the whole line as the domain, then $3xh+h^2$ is not $O(h)$, as 
$$
\frac{3xh+h^2}h=3x+h^2
$$
is not bounded.

As for your second question, yes, $O(h^2)/h=O(h)$.